# How to set an Environment Variable in Jenkins and send it to the deployed instance

Tags: deployment, jenkins, environment-variables

I would like to make able the users that start a build to choose the value for a SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE that can be used to switch the running instance deployed from PRODUCTION mode to DEV, I was able using envnject plugin to define the variable, but I don't know hot to pass this value to the maven build and then to the deployed instance.
I am new to this so I need the steps involved.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Parametrized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).

1. In your job tick "This build is parametrized"
2. Enter SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE
3. Now user value will be available in your Jenkins job
4. To pass this param to command line use ${SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE}
5. For maven goals and options enter:

   ```
   clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE}
   ```